# Debug Web Service em projeto secundário no Visual Studio

Tags: web-service, debug, breakpoints

Criei um novo projeto em C# no Visual Studio 2015 e fiz uma referência de um Web Service que está em um outro projeto secundário. Esse Web Service está funcionando normalmente, porém ao inserir o break point nada acontece. Poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Sim, podemos. Seja mais específico e dê mais detalhes sobre o seu problema. O projeto com o WebService está em outra solução? Você está rodando ele em modo Debug? Está usando IIS Express ou Local? **Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar informações a qualquer momento**

Comment: O projeto do WebService está na mesma solução, estou rodando em modo Debug e localmente.

Comment: Está rodando os dois projetos?

Comment: Estou rodando uma aplicação que chama uma função que está no WebService. Deixei o breakpoint nessa função que está no WebService.

Comment: E o webservice? Está rodando como debug também? Se não estiver, já sabe o problema...

Comment: Sim , os dois projetos estão.

Comment: E como você faz para rodar dois projetos na mesma solução em modo debug?

Comment: Deixei os dois projetos em modo debug. Executo primeiramente o projeto que irá chamar o método que está no Web Service. em seguida coloco o breakpoint no método que encontra-se no projeto do meu Web Service.